# Dominated convergence theorem exercise application

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

I have to prove that $$\lim_{n
\to \infty} \int_0^\infty \mathrm (1+x/n)^{-n}(x^{-1/n})\mathrm{d}x = 1$$

I've been told to use Dominated convergence theorem but I can't find a function $|f_n(x)| \le g(x)$.
Any tips to do that? Or should I try with another theorem?

Comment: I assume you mean to take the limit as $n$ goes to $\infty$, rather than $x$?

Comment: Hint: think of $e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not difficult to see that, if $n\geq2
 $, that $$\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n}x^{-1/n}\geq\left(1+\frac{x}{n+1}\right)^{-(n+1)}x^{-1/(n+1)}
 $$ so $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n}x^{-1/n}dx\leq\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{2}\right)^{-2}x^{-1/2}dx=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}
 $$ then we can apply the DCT, and so $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n}x^{-1/n}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n}x^{-1/n}dx
 $$ $$=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}dx=1.$$